# Create a filter with a multiple input Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

I'm gonna create a filter

here's my **model**

```
<?php
function show($branch,$department,$employee,$status,$from,$to,$category)
{
  $this->db->select('a.*,b.name,c.cityname');
  $this->db->from('expreport a');
  $this->db->join('expuser b','a.createdby=b.unique_id');
  $this->db->join('expcity c','a.cityid=c.citycode');

  if( $branch != "" ||  $status !="" || $from !="" || $to !="" || $department    !="" || $employee !="")
  {
    $this->db->select('d.employeename,e.branchname,f.deptname');
    $this->db->from('expemployee d');
    $this->db->join('expbranch e','d.branchid=e.branchcode');
    $this->db->join('expdepartment f','d.deptid=f.deptcode');
    $this->db->like('branchid', $branch);
    $this->db->or_like('deptid', $department);
    $this->db->or_like('employeeid', $employee);
    $this->db->where('status', $status);
    $this->db->where('fromdate <=',$from);
    $this->db->where('todate >=',$to);
  }

  if($category !="")
  {
    $this->db->select('g.category');
    $this->db->from('expcategory g');
    $this->db->like('catcode', $category);
  }

  $this->db->group_by('reportcode');
  $result = $this->db->get();
  echo $this->db->last_query();
  return $result->result();
}
?>
```

I have 7 inputs in view, I wanna separate the $branch,$status,$from,etc ,So the queries can execute from just 1 variable, So I don't have to input all variables,because when im just fill 1 input ,the queries don't execute

All Answers will be appreciated, Thank You :)

Comment: use only single variable $data in function parameter  when you pass to function from controller use $data['branch'] .

Comment: can u give some example pls ? @AmitChauhan

Comment: so i should make 7 functions in model ?? and once functions contain queries per input??

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar. I have a data filtering to show based on two filters. I have category filter and location filter.
Its in czech but the first row of radio buttons is category and the second row is location.

[image]

```
// After user hits "Show events"      
if($submit == "Submit"){
    //check if category filter was applied
    if(isset($category_filter) && $category_filter!='' && $category_filter!='everything'){
        //Add category number into variable and then into SQL query
        $cat_sql_condition = 'AND category='.$category_filter.'';
    }else{
        $cat_sql_condition='';
    }
    //check if location filter was applied
    if(isset($location_filter) && $location_filter!='' && $location_filter!='everything'){
        $loc_sql_condition = 'AND location_id='.$location_filter.'';
    }else{
        $loc_sql_condition='';
    }
    //Here i am creating the final query
    $query_string = "SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE visibility=1 AND start_date> ".$current_unix_timestamp." ".$cat_sql_condition." ".$loc_sql_condition." ORDER BY start_date;";
}else{
    //Without submit
    $query_string = "SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE visibility=1 AND start_date>'.$current_unix_timestamp.' ORDER BY start_date"; 
}
```